# 5V Linear Regulator outputting Vin-1V

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator

I designed a control circuit for a camera system. Most of the circuit works but except for a 5V regulator that outputs Vin-1V approximately. I checked 2 different ones on 2 different boards and both did the same thing. I have a bunch of them that I bought at the same time so it might be a batch problem but I'm not sure how to check that. Vin is usually between 12V and 15V.

Here is a picture of the regulator circuit:
[image: Regulator Circuit]

I'm at a loss as to what to check at this point so anything would help. And if I need to add anything else, let me know

ps: Here is the datasheet for the regulator:
[TI REG104 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/reg104.pdf)

edit: here is a picture of the whole schematic, maybe that might help. Sorry if my design is badly laid out.
[image]

Comment: What specific type reads on regulator? Are you sure you have the correct fixed 5V type instead of adjustable type regulator?

Comment: On the chip itself it reads "R104G50" on the first line and "86A3RFU" on the second line. On the order i made sure to get the one listed as fixed 5V output.

Comment: Do you have any kind of load on it, other than the meter?  It might be that the leakage in the regulator is more than that of the caps and meter.

Comment: Where did you buy them from?

Comment: Do your footprint's pin numbers match those in the datasheet?  Can something feed power back into the regulator when the input is disconnected?

Comment: I tried it without load and with a 220ohm 5W resistor with very little difference in voltage. the resistor was even getting hot. I bought them from Mouser:  https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/595-REG104GA-5

Comment: Pins seem to match up as well, and as far as I can tell, nothing feeds power to the output pin other than the regulator

Comment: According to the data sheet, C21 is the culprit. You need a resistor network, such as 34k/3.1k. There is no feedback from the output to control the output voltage, so it's no wonder you're getting weird results.

Comment: The resistor network is for the adjustable version. I have the fixed 5V version

Comment: As a diagnostic test, when enabled, does the NR/ADJ pin regulate to 1.295V ? Apparently it’s the feedback node, so if it is not close to 1.3V then the regulator is not regulating. If you try adding external resistor divider as though it was the adjustable version, and it works, then you did not receive the parts you were expecting. Though I agree the top mark does indicate the sot223 fixed 5v part.

Comment: If it fails to meet spec. It is either damaged, miswired or defective.

Comment: @MarkU Measuring the NR/ADJ pin does give me 1.29~V, i will try with a resistor divider to see if the markings are wrong.

Comment: I added the full schematic if that helps